# Can I use a $_POST to get info from database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

I'm trying to get info from an ID you type in to a form. To where the ID is the id it gets the info from that you entered the ID into the form. Here's the form & Mysql $row part..

```
<input type="text" class="DeathForms" name="userid" maxlength="4" /><br />

$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE id='".$_POST['userid']."'") 
or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
}
```

Now the part I'm trying to get is for it to display the rows from $_POST['userid']. Is it possible to do so? This is what I currently have..

```
<?php
if ( isset ( $_POST['userid'] ) )
{
file_put_contents('deathlist_' . $id . '.txt', "\n" . '
   <table width="800" align="center" class="DeathTable">
 <tr>
<td width="200" align="center" class="DeathName"><a class="DeathName" href="user?id=' .     $_POST['userid'] .'">' . $row['name'] . '</a></td>
<td width="200" align="center" class="DeathLevel">' . $_POST['threat'] . '</td> 
</tr>
</table><br />' . file_get_contents ( 'deathlist_' . $id . '.txt' ) );
}

?>

          <?php
      if ( file_exists ( 'deathlist_' . $id . '.txt' ) )
      {
        echo  file_get_contents('deathlist_' . $id . '.txt') . '</span>';
      }
      ?>
```

Is it possible to get database from the id of $_POST['userid']?

Answer (score 1):

First tip: Assuming this just isn't some example data, you really should at least be escaping the variables that you use in your query, or more preferably using PDO or MySQLi.

I'm not exactly sure I understand what you're asking. As long as you reference the column name correctly inside the `while()` loop (i.e `$row["column_name"]`) and echo it out everything should be fine.

Comment: Well, I'm using file_put_contents so it inserts it into a text file and then gets it, so I can't just echo it out onto the webpage

Answer (score 0):

You need to `echo` it (if I understand your question)

```
echo $_POST['userid'];
```

Comment: Well, it's inserting it into a text file, and then echoing it back out with file_get_contents

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if ( isset ( $_POST['userid'] ) ){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE id='".$_POST['userid']."'") 
              or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
        echo $row['threat'];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Well, it's inserting into a .txt file, so can't just echo it out into the webpage.

Comment: Use file_put_contents then.

Comment: set a single variable containing all the data from database and use file_put_contents